# appointment of a route between two points in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, frontend

I've got a problem with designating a route between two points. So 
the matter is as follows I have one fixed point of an initial and several places with descriptions and button routing, when i push the routing button on the map appears  next to the route from the starting point to the desired location.
I hope that you would be able to help me.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <button onclick="">Route to point one</button>
      <button oclick="">Route to point two</button>

    <div id="map">Route</div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178,17.922616861760616),
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178,17.922616861760616),
                     map: map


                 });
          var endmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178,17.922616861760616),
                     map: map


                 });
        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };

      endmarker.addEventListener('click', onChangeHandler);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin:  new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178,17.922616861760625),
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'WALKING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add button click functions to route to various points, one option would be to modify the `calculateAndDisplayRoute` to take the second point as an argument.

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(point) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178, 17.922616861760625),
    destination: point,
    travelMode: 'WALKING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Define the points (and the directions service/renderer) in the global scope:

```
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplay;
var point1 = {lat: 50.669552,lng: 17.914806};
var point2 = {lat: 50.669151, lng: 17.932956};
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="calculateAndDisplayRoute(point1);">Route to point one</button>
<button onclick="calculateAndDisplayRoute(point2);">Route to point two</button>
```

**code snippet:**

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculateAndDisplayRoute(point1);">Route to point one</button>
<button onclick="calculateAndDisplayRoute(point2);">Route to point two</button>

<div id="map">Route</div>
<script>
  var directionsService;
  var directionsDisplay;
  var point1 = {
    lat: 50.669552,
    lng: 17.914806
  };
  var point2 = {
    lat: 50.669151,
    lng: 17.932956
  };

  function initMap() {
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178, 17.922616861760616),
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178, 17.922616861760616),
      map: map


    });
    var endmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178, 17.922616861760616),
      map: map
    });
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(point) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: new google.maps.LatLng(50.66956513913178, 17.922616861760625),
      destination: point,
      travelMode: 'WALKING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
</script>
```